# count number of columns in table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table in this format. Now i need to count the number of P in month 5 and 6. I need all the P in month 5 but only need P till DAY15 in month 6.

[image: picture]
 Code I tried is ::

```
create or replace PROCEDURE total_att  IS
    cols varchar2(4000);
    col varchar2(4000);
    i number;
    where_str varchar2(4000);
    sqlstr varchar2(4000);
    BEGIN
    for i in 1..31 loop
    col:='day' || i;
    cols:=cols||col ||',';
    where_str:=where_str || col ||'=''P'' OR ';
    end loop;
    cols:=substr(cols,1,length(cols)-1);
    sqlstr:='SELECT MONTH,'||cols||' from hss_attendance where '|| where_str ;
    sqlstr:=substr(sqlstr,1,length(sqlstr)-3) ' ;
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlstr);
    END total_att;
```

next code i tried was ::

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE total_att_new  IS
    cols varchar2(4000);
    col varchar2(4000);
    i number;
    where_str varchar2(4000);
    sqlstr varchar2(4000);
    sqlstrs clob;
    BEGIN
    for i in 1..32 loop
    col:='day' || i;
    sqlstr:='select month,
    case '||col||' when ''P''
    then 1 else 0 end as att
    from hss_attendance
    where student_id = ''4003''
    and month=''4''
    union ';
    sqlstrs:=sqlstrs || sqlstr;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlstrs);
    END total_att_new;
```

Comment: This looks like really bad table design.  How would this scale for multiple years?  With regard to your question, you might need some dynamic SQL here to filter the columns you want by building a name via `DAY` plus some number.

Comment: In this table I have some more columns including year as well. In this image i have put only month and day column. and of course I am expecting dynamic query for this

Comment: Please post data as formatted test, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, what have you tried so far? Please post your code and explain the problem you are having with it

Comment: In this request you are asking how to sum Ps from May 1 to June 15. Now it shows what you actually wanted to ask is how to sum Ps for a date range that is specified when running the query. This is something entirely different, so please pay more attention next time you make a request.

Comment: Please post solution if you have any

Comment: You don't need either "dynamic SQL" or "Procedure" for this; the columns are fixed. The proper solution is to normalize your table design, but with what you have now, Aleksej showed you already how to do this in plain SQL. Any other solution will be much harder to maintain and much more inefficient than simply unpivoting first (making the data normal for further processing).

Comment: That table design is shameful :(

Answer (score 2):

This could be an approach, with no need for dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT count(case when value = 'P' then 1 end)
FROM   horribleTable
UNPIVOT (value FOR dy IN (
                            DAY1  as '1',
                            DAY2  as '2',
                            DAY3  as '3',
                            DAY4  as '4',  
                            DAY5  as '5',
                            DAY6  as '6',
                            DAY7  as '7',
                            DAY8  as '8',
                            DAY9  as '9',
                            DAY10 as '10',
                            DAY11 as '11',
                            DAY12 as '12',
                            DAY13 as '13',
                            DAY14 as '14',
                            DAY15 as '15',
                            DAY16 as '16',
                            DAY17 as '17',
                            DAY18 as '18',
                            DAY19 as '19',
                            DAY20 as '20',
                            DAY21 as '21',
                            DAY22 as '22',
                            DAY23 as '23',
                            DAY24 as '24',
                            DAY25 as '25',
                            DAY26 as '26',
                            DAY27 as '27',
                            DAY28 as '28',
                            DAY29 as '29',
                            DAY30 as '30',
                            DAY31 as '31')
)
where (mth = 5 or (mth = 6 and dy <= 15))
  and yr = 2016    --  optional
;
```

The [UNPIVOT](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) trasnposes your columns into rows, so that you can apply a filter based on day; the `count` and the `case` simply check for the value 'P', while the filters for month and year are straightforward

Comment: I edited the code for two things: First, the OP wanted all days in month 5 and the first 15 days in month 6 (so `month = 5 and day < 15` were both incorrect). And, `day`, `month` and `year` are all reserved words in Oracle and should not be used for column names. I changed the column names to `dy, mth, yr`.

Comment: You could also simply `count(value)` in this case (assuming the other "values" are NULL). UNPIVOT will not create rows for the NULL values - and even if it did, `count(column-name)` does not include NULLs in the count.

Comment: @mathguy - Absolutely right, thanks. For the values, it seems that the OP can have values like  'A', so I preferred to keep something he could easily adapt

Comment: I am using toad for oracle. when i use above query it is not talking UNPIVOT as key word as a result it says  :ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @AnilBirSinghTuladhar: I believe it's not a matter of Toad. Which Oracle version?

Comment: I am using oracle 10 g

Answer (score 1):

The table design is horrible, but the query is accordingly long but still easy:

```
select month,
  case when day1 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day2 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day3 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day4 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  ...
  case when day31 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end as days
from mytable
where month = 5
union all
select month,
  case when day1 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day2 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day3 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day4 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  ...
  case when day15 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end as days
from mytable
where month = 6
```

This gives you the sums per month. If you want one sum for both months instead do:

```
select month,
  case when day1 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day2 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day3 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day4 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  ...
  case when day15 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when month = 5 and day16 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when month = 5 and day17 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  ...
  case when month = 5 and day31 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end as days
from mytable
where month in (5, 6);
```

Here is the second query for a given :from_month, :from_day, :till_month, :till_day:

```
select month,
  case when day1 = 'P' 
       and not (month = :from_month and 1 < :from_day)
       and not (month = :till_month and 1 > :till_day)
  then 1 else 0 end +
  case when day2 = 'P'
       and not (month = :from_month and 2 < :from_day)
       and not (month = :till_month and 2 > :till_day)
  then 1 else 0 end +
  ...
  case when day31 = 'P'
       and not (month = :from_month and 31 < :from_day)
       and not (month = :till_month and 31 > :till_day)
  then 1 else 0 end as days
from mytable
where month between :from_month and :till_month;
```

But better change your table design, so queries will be much simpler with a lot less typing :-)

Comment: This is kind of static query .Day and month is going to be input parameter, hence it can be any day between 1 to 31 and any month between 1-12, so i need dynamic query if you can help me

Comment: Which of the two queries do you need; one total or one sum per month?

Comment: i need total number of P. IF input parameter is month 6 and day 15 then, I need total number of P from month one till 15th of 6 th month

Comment: Okay, I've added such a query to my answer. You will notice it's just the same thing only with variables.

Comment: What does "still not working" mean? An error? An incorrect sum? What else? And have you even checked the query in order to find out what's wrong with it?

Comment: It returns 0 in days in all month. I am confuse in this portion of code 
"and not (month = :from_month and 2 < :from_day)
and not (month = :till_month and 2 > :till_day)"

Comment: I put from_month=1 ,from_day=1,till_month=5 and till_day=15 in all . and it is not working, result is 0 in days column with multiple month

Comment: Well, the code translates to: when the record we are currently looking at is the from_month and the from_day is later than day 2, then don't consider the DAY2 column; and when the the record we are currently looking at is the till_month and the till_day is before day 2 then don't consider the DAY2 column either. For any other month or any other day DAY2 will be added. I don't see any flaw in this.